# Typo3 6.0 - Extending tx_news

Tags: typo3, field, extend, builder, tx-news

I am new in Typo3, and I tried to extend News following this tutorial : http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Tutorial/ExtendingNews/Index.html

My main goal is to create a new extension, which I did using Extension Builder, and then extend News so I can add a new field and use it.

I followed every step described in the tutorial, but there's one point which I'm not sure about how to proceed. 
Where and how am I supposed to use my new custom field in the template?

In the tutorial, it is written :

> "You can now use the new field in the template by using
>   {newsItem.txWorkshopTitle}or {newsItem.workshopTitle}".

Where am I supposed to put this line ? Do I need to make a custom template in my own extension? I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create custom templates by copying the default Fluid templates from 
EXT:news/Resources/Private/* into a new folder, for example to fileadmin/templates/ext/news/

Then you need to configure the path to your custom template with TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_news {
    view {
        templateRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Templates
        partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Partials
        layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Layouts
        }
}
```

Alternatively you can put this stuff into your own extension. Then you'd need some settings like:

```
...
templateRootPath = EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/tx_news/Templates
...
```

and put the above mentioned copies into Resources/Private/tx_news/

Now you can customize the templates in fileadmin/templates/ext/news/ and use your own accessor to it.